# Technology recommendation required for iOS and Android Apps for dynamic UI

Tags: android, ios, forms, web-services, dynamic

It is required to develop an application which should work on both iOS and Android. The fields to be displayed on loan application form are dynamic and hence depends on the webservice response. There are even fields which are displayed with respect to the user selection on drop-down

**Device Compatibility :** iOS, Android

**Fields contain :** Textfield, Dropdown, radio button, Labels for titles, Checkbox.

Suggest a technology other than native languages like Objective C,Swift/Java.

**JSON response is given below**

```
[
{
    "title": "Tab1",
    "Contents": [
        {
            "title": "Personal Details",
            "Values": [
                {
                    "id": "0",
                    "fieldvalue": "radio",
                    "label": "Salutation",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "id": "1",
                            "label": "Mr"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "2",
                            "label": "Mrs"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "3",
                            "label": "Others"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "fieldname": "UserName",
                    "fieldvalue": "string",
                    "label": "FIRST NAME",
                    "length": "30"
                },
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "fieldname": "UserName",
                    "fieldvalue": "string",
                    "label": "LAST NAME",
                    "length": "30"
                },
                {
                    "id": "3",
                    "fieldname": "UserName",
                    "fieldvalue": "string",
                    "label": "MOTHERS NAME",
                    "length": "30"
                },
                {
                    "id": "4",
                    "fieldname": "UserName",
                    "fieldvalue": "string",
                    "label": "FAMILY NAME",
                    "length": "30"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5",
                    "fieldname": "UserName",
                    "fieldvalue": "selector",
                    "label": "GENDER",
                    "values": [
                        "Male",
                        "Female",
                        "Others"
                    ],
                    "length": "30"
                },
                {
                    "id": "6",
                    "fieldname": "UserName",
                    "fieldvalue": "selector",
                    "label": "Education",
                    "values": [
                        "Graduate",
                        "Post Graduate",
                        "School Level",
                        "Illitrate"
                    ],
                    "length": "30"
                },
                {
                    "id": "7",
                    "fieldname": "DOB",
                    "fieldvalue": "string",
                    "label": "DOB",
                    "length": "10"
                },
                {
                    "id": "8",
                    "fieldname": "Nationality",
                    "fieldvalue": "selector",
                    "values": [
                        "India",
                        "America",
                        "Britian",
                        "Arabia",
                        "Dubai"
                    ],
                    "label": "Nationality",
                    "length": "10"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Residential Address ",
            "Values": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "fieldvalue": "string",
                    "fieldname": "housename",
                    "length": 30,
                    "label": "House Name"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "fieldvalue": "string",
                    "fieldname": "city",
                    "length": 30,
                    "label": "City"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "fieldvalue": "string",
                    "fieldname": "district",
                    "length": 30,
                    "label": "District"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Communication Details ",
            "Values": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "fieldvalue": "string",
                    "fieldname": "housename",
                    "length": 30,
                    "label": "House Name"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "fieldvalue": "string",
                    "fieldname": "city",
                    "length": 30,
                    "label": "City"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "fieldvalue": "string",
                    "fieldname": "district",
                    "length": 30,
                    "label": "District"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "title": "Tab2",
    "Contents": [
        {
            "title": "Employement Details",
            "id ": "0",
            "fieldvalue": "radio",
            "label": "Occupation",
            "Values": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "label": "Salaried",
                    "fields": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "fieldName": "companyname",
                            "fieldvalue": "string",
                            "length": "30",
                            "label": "Company Name",
                            "isrequired": true
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 2,
                            "fieldName": "designation",
                            "fieldvalue": "string",
                            "length": "30",
                            "label": "Designation",
                            "isrequired": true
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 3,
                            "fieldName": "joindate",
                            "fieldvalue": "string",
                            "length": "30",
                            "label": "Joing Date",
                            "isrequired": true
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 4,
                            "fieldName": "skills",
                            "fieldvalue": "string",
                            "length": "30",
                            "label": "Skills",
                            "isrequired": true
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 5,
                            "fieldName": "experience",
                            "fieldvalue": "string",
                            "length": "30",
                            "label": "Total Experience",
                            "isrequired": true
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "label": "Self Employed",
                    "fields": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "fieldName": "companyname",
                            "fieldvalue": "string",
                            "length": "30",
                            "label": "Company Name",
                            "isrequired": true
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 2,
                            "fieldName": "designation",
                            "fieldvalue": "string",
                            "length": "30",
                            "label": "Designation",
                            "isrequired": true
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 3,
                            "fieldName": "establihmentdate",
                            "fieldvalue": "string",
                            "length": "30",
                            "label": "Established Date",
                            "isrequired": true
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 4,
                            "fieldName": "projects",
                            "fieldvalue": "string",
                            "length": "30",
                            "label": "Projects Done",
                            "isrequired": true
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 5,
                            "fieldName": "employees",
                            "fieldvalue": "string",
                            "length": "30",
                            "label": "Employee strength",
                            "isrequired": true
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "label": "Un Employed",
                    "fields": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "fieldName": "employment",
                            "fieldvalue": "string",
                            "length": "30",
                            "label": "Employment Mode",
                            "isrequired": true
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 2,
                            "fieldName": "income",
                            "fieldvalue": "string",
                            "length": "30",
                            "label": "Monthly Income",
                            "isrequired": true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "title": "Tab3",
    "Contents": [
        {
            "title": "Account Details",
            "id ": "0",
            "fieldvalue": "selector",
            "Values": [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "fieldname": "Car Loan",
                    "fields": [
                        {
                            "id": "1",
                            "fieldvalue": "number",
                            "label": "Loan Amount",
                            "isrequired": true,
                            "length": "30"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "2",
                            "fieldvalue": "number",
                            "label": "Tenure",
                            "isrequired": true,
                            "length": "30"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "3",
                            "fieldvalue": "number",
                            "label": "Interest Rate",
                            "isrequired": true,
                            "length": "30"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "4",
                            "fieldvalue": "selector",
                            "label": "CAR MAKE",
                            "isrequired": true,
                            "length": "30",
                            "values": [
                                "Maruti",
                                "Honda",
                                "Renault",
                                "Mahindra",
                                "Ford",
                                "Fiat"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "5",
                            "fieldvalue": "selector",
                            "label": "FUEL TYPE",
                            "isrequired": true,
                            "length": "30",
                            "values": [
                                "Petrol",
                                "Diesel",
                                "Electric"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "fieldname": "Home",
                    "fields": [
                        {
                            "id": "1",
                            "fieldvalue": "number",
                            "label": "Loan Amount",
                            "isrequired": true,
                            "length": "30"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "2",
                            "fieldvalue": "number",
                            "label": "Tenure",
                            "isrequired": true,
                            "length": "30"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "3",
                            "fieldvalue": "number",
                            "label": "Interest Rate",
                            "isrequired": true,
                            "length": "30"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can develop haybrid app by using folowing technology

1. [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/)
2. [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/)
3. [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com)
4. [framework 7](https://framework7.io)
5. [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com)

I personally recommend **Ionic**

but before dive into it you need to know the pros and cons of this technology. 
Some helpful link
https://ymedialabs.com/hybrid-vs-native-mobile-apps-the-answer-is-clear/
[www.mobiloud.com/blog/native-web-or-hybrid-apps/](http://www.mobiloud.com/blog/native-web-or-hybrid-apps/)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is really really generic. There are dozens of valid alternatives, it really depends on your requirements. Building a dynamic UI requires more than just choosing a "technology". You can obtain that with any language. What I would do is serialize the API call, and then build the UI according to the objects returned by the API "config" call. Still, you can achieve this with native technology (like [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) and [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) in Android). You could use [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com) to develop the app in C# and have a shared code between the iOS and Android app. You could use [React Native](https://github.com/facebook/react-native). I would not choose my language/platform based on your requirement.